# How to use CloudFunctions in a Xamarin project

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-functions

Is there a tutorial on how to properly call a cloud function using Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudFunctions? Or how to setup a regular http request for it, without the library?

I set up my function like this:

```
exports.IsAppleSubscriptionActive = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {});'''
```

and deployed it like this:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

and got and url like this:

```
https://[region]-[project-id].cloudfunctions.net/IsAppleSubscriptionActive
```

On the client I installed the nuget and I try calling:

```
var result = await CloudFunctions.DefaultInstance.HttpsCallable("IsAppleSubscriptionActive").CallAsync(payloadToSend);
```

where payloadToSend is a NSDictionary.
I get

```
Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=com.firebase.functions Code=13 "INTERNAL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=INTERNAL}
```

What am I missing? I feel like the native tutorials aren't helping either.

When using a regular http request I get a 500 status, in the logs I see something related to permissions accessing the secret manager (I use it for some api keys).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there was nothing wrong with the code, I just wasn't giving the proper permissions to the proper user (I was using Secret Manager in my cloud function)